# change the anchor (location.hash) in the address-bar

Tags: api, iframe, facebook-iframe

I have an FB application that uses the anchor (document.location.hash) to set tags on different elements (for example the current TAB#, the group# that is displayed...).
So whenever the user changes these elemets, I change the anchor (location.hash) and it adds #tag=...
to the URL in the address-bar (and when the user copy the link and sends it to another user) he is redirected to the specific view (on the same page).

It works well when the app is a standalone site.
But when I put it under FB application (apps.facebook.com/myapp) - it does not change the URL in the address-bar (but when I read the document.location.has I see the change). I think maybe it is because my app is inside an IFRAME. 
If it cannot be fixed, maybe there is a Facebook API that changes the hash part in the URL!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to change the parts of `location` object of parent frame if it's served from different domain... You can only change the whole location by setting it to new value:

```
window.top.location = 'http://example.com';
```

Actually `document.location` always refers to current document, while window.location refers to top level document and represent the URL that user see in address bar of the browser.

So generally you changed the hash for current document and if it's opened as standalone site user sees that in address bar, but once running in frame (application canvas) user doesn't see the URL of that page, but parent frame which located on other domain and subject of cross-domain policy.